# Loading yahoo finance data from pandas datareader

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

In order to analize Apple stocks data in Python I tried to load them using Pandas datareader and Yahoo! Finance. In order to do so, after importing pandas datareader I tried to run the following lines of code:

```
import yfinance as yf
yf.override()
AAPL.df = pdr.data.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start=start)[Adj Close].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
```

After doing this I got this error message:

```
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\folder\Fama-French.ipynb Cella 11 in <cell line: 2>()
----> 1 AAPL_df = pdr.DataReader(name='AAPL', start=start, data_source='yahoo')
      2 AAPL_df.pct_change()

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:207, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    205     else:
    206         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 207 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py:379, in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    367     raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    369 if data_source == "yahoo":
    370     return YahooDailyReader(
    371         symbols=name,
    372         start=start,
    373         end=end,
    374         adjust_price=False,
    375         chunksize=25,
    376         retry_count=retry_count,
    377         pause=pause,
    378         session=session,
--> 379     ).read()
...
--> 126     unix_start = int(time.mktime(self.start.timetuple()))
    127     unix_start += four_hours_in_seconds
    128     day_end = self.end.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59)

OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```

What happened? And, most imporant, what should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: what are the attribute values that you are passing

Comment: Can you post what type and value is your ```start``` argument?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve the problem by checking what the author has written in his github or [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/). Apparently, you want to override it with yfinance package.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

AAPL_df= pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL')['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed

AAPL_df
Out[8]: 
Date
1980-12-31         NaN
1981-01-31   -0.172163
1981-02-28   -0.061943
1981-03-31   -0.075475
1981-04-30    0.158163
  
2022-03-31    0.057473
2022-04-30   -0.097131
2022-05-31   -0.054496
2022-06-30   -0.081430
2022-07-31    0.188634
Freq: M, Name: Adj Close, Length: 500, dtype: float64
```